# OS-independent random byte sequence in PHP

Tags: php, security, random

I would like to generate a random byte sequence to be used in a security-sensitive context. I am looking for an OS-independent way, so I cannot access /dev/(u)random. Furthermore, openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() might not be available so let's forget about it too. I am also not interested in performance differences in any of the cases.

Looking at the phpass library (which is used by many and considered to be secure enough) to generate random sequences it falls back to to following algorithm if /dev/urandom is not available:

```
// Init:
$this->random_state = microtime();
if (function_exists('getmypid'))
    $this->random_state .= getmypid();

// Generate
$count = ...number of bytes to generate
$output = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16) {
    $this->random_state =
        md5(microtime() . $this->random_state);
    $output .=
        pack('H*', md5($this->random_state));
}
$output = substr($output, 0, $count);
// $output ready
```

The above algorithm basically relies on getmypid(), md5() and microtime() to generate random sequences. It has been pointed out by many that time/microtime and pid are a bad source of entropy for secure applications, and so even if you transform these with md5 and some string operations, the output won't be 'securely random' either. So we know that the above algorithm is at best only as good as pid and microtime are as entropy sources.

In contrast here is another algorithm. Given that rand is seeded automatically by PHP, it is (probably) not better than the previous algorithm security-wise since rand/mt_rand are also seeded with computer time and pid by default ([ref](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76229/predicting-the-output-of-phps-rand)). But since it is much less complex, wouldn't it be a better alternative? I can also rephrase the question: given that both the algorithm above and that below rely on pid and computer time to generate random numbers, should the above still be superior and why?

```
function RandomBytes($len)
{
    // Seed
    $seed = (double)microtime()*1000003;
    if (function_exists('getmypid'))
            $seed += getmypid();
    mt_srand($seed);

    $output = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i)
        $output .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));

    // optionally transform using pack('H*', ...) to make output printable
    return $output;
}
```

And as a last question, do you know a better (=more random) way than any of the above to generate random bytes in an OS-independent manner in PHP?

Comment: There is no portable and always-available way to generate cryptographically strong random byte sequences in PHP. You need a specific environment or tools available, which you ruled out with your preconditions. -- The reason phpass uses just rand or the hash workaround is that it just uses it as password salt, which does not depend on high entropy.

Comment: I do understand that without OS support I won't be able to generate cryptographically secure random sequences. But how does the second algorithm I've shown compare to the first one, and (why) is one of them better than the other?

Comment: mt_rand and rand are already seeded,  you are acutally making these functions less secure by reducing the entropy of the seed.

Comment: The first algorithm also seems to seed similarly. Would anything change considerably if I removed the seeding part in RandomBytes()?

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to use OS resources if they exist, and then fall back to something homegrown when these resources do not exist and you have no other choice. See [this answer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php#83655) on another forum for an example.

On Windows systems that support .NET you can use the DOTNET php class together with the `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to rely on OS implemented pseudo-random generator, if strongly correctness is required. Specially for security and simulations. Pseudo random generators are not difficult to be implemented, have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) for a bit of theory and some references.

Answer (score 0):

The best random number generator you can possibly use is `/dev/random`.  If this interface is not accessible then you maybe on a windows system in that case you can use the much less secure `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.  The function `mt_rand()` should be a distant 3rd place in terms of how random its output is.